# Selenium web page takes too long to completed loading,how to set timeout in case of slow internet

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, web

I have created a facebook bot that logs in after a time but in case of slow internet i want bot to stop and close driver but i can't perform this operation until the page is loaded.

Comment: We don't know how you loading pages

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use a timeout to load the page wrapped in try-catch mechanism.
If the page does not load within the given time, then the driver should close.
Now, I am a python guy and so I cannot write code in JS and show you, but you may transform this to your language as required.

```
driver.get('x.com')

    try:
        # wait until an element in the page loads (typically one of the last elements that loads) within the given time (here it is 10 seconds timeout)
        webdriverwait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH,  "locator"),10)
    except:
        driver.close()
```

OR

You may try IMPLICIT_WAIT with a timeout.
Eg:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```